# Decoding .BIN Binary File Python

Tags: python, binary, decode

I'm new to decoding bin files and am a bit lost after reaching the point where I can get this type of information from the file:

```
b'\xb8\xa3\r\xd1\x18]\xbd\x14\x11\x03\x91n\xc5\x88%\x004\x05\x01\x00\x00\x00\xe9B\x04\xd1\x18]\xbd\x14\x08\x01'
```

I honestly have no idea where to go from here. I've tried using struct and that hasn't helped. Any help would be appreciated. I will answer any questions to the best of my ability. My results should be tick data if that is any help.

Answer (score 0):

`struct` library is the right thing to decode binary data. however, you need to have some information about the data itself if you want to unpack this file. If this is tick data then you should have information about its structure like types of fields, row length, information about byte order etc. maybe there is documentation or something?

Comment: from what i can gather 'x' is a place holder, i haven't been able to find any documentation to narrow down the decoding further but I will ask some colleagues at work if there is anything. would it be possible(efficient) to write a try/else loop to attempt to decode? looks like its not a standard consistent format throughout the file.